# Error converting nvarchar to datetime data type using Laravel and MSSQL

Tags: php, laravel

I installed successfully Laravel on IIS. I connected the MSSQL DB also successfully with laravel. I run the artisan command `php artisan make:auth` and `php artisan migrate`.To make a login/register pages. Now when i register a new user i get an error.:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Bei der Konvertierung eines nvarchar-Datentyps in einen
>   datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs.
>   (SQL: insert into [users] ([name], [email], [password], [updated_at],
>   [created_at]) values (john doe, j.doe@example.com,
>   $2y$10$zPpJKp.clN8/SrhBhrupmO1ydWFb6UmrAUaD0Wid7fQHt85ieSwNi,
>   2018-04-24 10:03:26.286, 2018-04-24 10:03:26.286))

this translated to english:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value."

my migration look like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->tinyInteger('active')->default(1);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and my db after migration look like this:
[image]

In MSSQL i'm using the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. 
DO have anybody any idea whats the problem is?

**UPDATE**
'Quick solution: I changed the mssql columns created_at and updated_at to nvarchars(50)

**UPDATE1**
Another solution is to override it with this method

```
public function fromDateTime($value)
{
    // Only for MSSQL
    if(env('DB_CONNECTION') == 'sqlsrv') {
        return Carbon::parse(parent::fromDateTime($value))->format('Y-d-m H:i:s:000');
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If somebody face this problem, i solved using 
protected $dateFormat = 'd-m-Y H:i:s'; //Format as you need
in the Model.

Comment: In my case, I solved it using the ANSI format: "Ymd H:i:s.v". This is accepted whatever language you are using

Answer (score 1):

If the answer from Jefers isn't working try this in your Model:

```
public function getDateFormat(){
    return 'Y-d-m H:i:s.v';
}
```